# Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server after setup https in local wampserver

Tags: apache, https, permissions, wampserver

I have set my local wampserver to https by following this [tutorial](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,32986)

and now all is done and I can access php files with `https://localhost/......`

but when I want to access files from other device in the same local network with the ip adress  (I have got from ipconfig )192.168.1.46

I have this error

```
    Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

how can I fix this issue

Answer (score 2):

I fix this issue by adding those lines at the end of httpd.conf of my apache2.2.11 :

```
    <Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
 #Options FollowSymLinks
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
 AllowOverride None
 Allow from all
</Directory>
```